# Crossref API output

Tags: python, api, cross-reference

I'm trying to figure out the output in the crossref.org API.  Using a python script, my goal is to take either a DOI or article/author name and output the inverse.  So when they enter in an article name, my hope is to output a list of DOI's.

```
from habanero import Crossref

cr = Crossref()

article_input = raw_input('Enter name/author/DOI of article:')

if type(input) == 'int': # checks if input is an integer
    # deal with doi
    article_output = cr.works(article_input)
   # article_output['message']
   # article_output['message']['total-results']
   # article_output['message']['items']
    print(article_output)
if type(input) == 'str': # checks if input is a string
    # deal with title/author
    doi = cr.works(query=article_input)
   # doi['message']
   # doi['message']['total-results']
   # doi['message']['items']
    print(doi)
```

Comment: Do you have a question or problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The print doesn't actually do anything.